Confusing point point in Dyna-Q
Sutton-Barto, page 164:

In the (f) loop, $S,A, S', R$ are from real experience (Model(S,A)=(R, S') where R and S' are also real expereince).
This experience is used in direct RL part in (d). Why is the same experience used
again in the (f) part? Q-update in (d) uses the same info as Q-update in (f). I am totally confused.
It seems to me that part (f) is a n-times re-application in parts before it.

The hope in (f) is that the ${max}_aQ(S^\prime,a)$ has changed since it was previously evaluated so that it's effect on the present state's value can be propagated without the agent having to spend the steps to experience it.
